# Yoast makes comment_reply_link function output plain link to comment instead of reply link

Tags: comments

EDITED - I discovered that my problem only arises when the Yoast plugin is active. But I want to keep Yoast active, so my updated question is: Any idea what to do for comment replies working while Yoast is activated?

Here's my original question:

In a custom theme created by myself, or rather its child theme on a multisite, I am having trouble with the `comment_reply_link` function. I am using it as follows:

```
<?php comment_reply_link(array_merge( $args, array('depth' => $depth, 'max_depth' => $args['max_depth']))) ?>
```

Now on the website, the link doesn't result in the expected `/?replytocom=6#respond` appended to the URL of the post, but simply in a local `#comment-6` `href` attribute for the link. So when a user clicks on "Reply", nothing happens. When he/she writes a reply then, it is posted as a first-level reply, not as a reply to the intended previous comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Version 7 of WordPress SEO by Yoast](https://yoast.com/yoast-seo-7-0/) removes the replytocom variables by default.

> We’ve removed the option to turn off the replytocom variable. The replytocom feature in WordPress lets you reply to comments without activating JavaScript in your browser. However, every comment gets is own link and these could all end up in the search engines. So we now remove these variables by default.

To [get the replytcom variables back](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-get-replytocom-back/) we can add the following filter in our theme's `functions.php`

```
add_filter( 'wpseo_remove_reply_to_com', '__return_false' );
```

Comment: thank you, that works.